# nbsp character might not be passing as nbsp to the MySQL backend

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, character

I am following a tutorial where a web application written in PHP, blacklists spaces from the input(The 'id' parameter). The task is to add other characters, which essentially bypasses this blacklist, but still gets interpreted by the MySQL database in the back end. Considering that the nbsp character is not blacklisted, I construct a URL like so - `http://192.168.2.15/sqli-labs/Less-26/?id=1'%C2%A0||%C2A0'1`, where `C2A0` is the UTF-8 representation of the nbsp character. This however throws a MySQL error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' || '1' LIMIT 0,1' at line 1`

I reflect the SQL query string that runs on the database back on to the page

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1' || '1' LIMIT 0,1`

This query seems alright to me and it shouldn't throw an error. I suspect that it might have something to do with character sets. But I have very limited understanding of character sets in MySQL and in what situations which character set applies.

What I see when I run `show variables like 'char%';`

`+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | gbk                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+`

Comment: The non-breaking space character is not equivalent to a space character and MySQL will not interpret it as a space character, even though it looks like a space to you and me. Your query is invalid for the same reason `id='1'✖||✖'1'` is invalid—you replaced a space with something that isn't a space.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL *syntax* does not recognize utf8 `C2A0`.
In this test, note the regular space (`20`) and the `NO-BREAK SPACE` (`C2A0`):

```
mysql> select UNHEX('53454C45435420313B'), UNHEX('53454C454354C2A0323B');
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
| UNHEX('53454C45435420313B') | UNHEX('53454C454354C2A0323B') |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
| SELECT 1;                   | SELECT 2;                     |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I copied those two statements over:

```
mysql> SELECT 1;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 2;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
   for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 2' at line 1
```